# How to create PagedList from DataTable for Pagination

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, pagination, ado.net

I am in ASP.NET MVC, and I am currently using ADO.NET to query my database, fill a DataTable, then passing the DataTable to my view to display the data on the screen. (*I am purposely not following MVC best practices, im just trying to figure out a concept*)

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (AdomdConnection con = new AdomdConnection(consString))
        {
            con.Open();
            AdomdCommand query = new AdomdCommand("Some query blah blah", con);
            AdomdDataAdapter da = new AdomdDataAdapter(query);

            da.Fill(dt);      
        }
        return View(dt);
}
```

And in the View

```
@model System.Data.DataTable
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<table id="infoTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <th>Discount Amount</th>
        <th>Sales Count</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
@foreach(System.Data.DataRow row in Model.Rows)
{
   <tr>
       @foreach(var cell in row.ItemArray)
       {
           <td>@cell</td>
       }
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

This currently displays all the data rows on my screen. I want to add Pagination, so  that only a few records will display on the screen at a time, and uses a control at the bottom of the table to view more records.

I have found PagedList, and the concept seems like it would work well. Instead of passing my DataTable to my view, I want to pass a PagedList, but I am not sure how to convert my DataTable to a PagedList.

Does anyone know how I can take my DataTable, make it into a PagedList, then pass the PagedList to my view for Pagination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I separated my DataTable into its own Model as it should be, then in this model,

I created

```
public List<DataRow> list { get; set;}//Regular list to hold data from Datatable
public PagedList<DataRow> plist { get; set; }//Paged list for pagination to be filled with data from regular List
```

I then casted my DataTable to a List

```
list = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList();
```

Then I initialized my PagedList using my List

```
plist = new PagedList<DataRow>(list, page ?? 1, 5);
```

I was then able to pass this Model to my View, with the ability to iterate through my PagedList

```
plist
```

Comment: Hi, this is what i'm also looking for, can you please help me to answer that how i can use it in Razor View? I'm bit confused here, people are using @model IPagedList<ContosoUniversity.Models.Student>  kind of stuff. If i return plist what would be the modal and IPagedList, thanks you.

Comment: Incomplete answer, show the view too. Plus code has exception too. It should be `dt.AsQueryable`